# After archiving xamarin forms app to apk, it does not work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, apk

I have my xamarin app, when i start it form VS2019 in Release or Debug mode it works great.
If i archive it with visual studio, sign and install to mine or other android phone, it crashes.

Comment: Did you enable the `Linker` when you archiving your application like this thread?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker If so, please disable all of them, re-archive your application and test again.

Comment: Review the logcat output to determine why the app is crashing and/or the installation is failing. Without that information, anything else is just a guess: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=macos…

Comment: Thanks to all. Itself did not guess to get a logcat. The problem was in SQLite, just the program tries access to a table that does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APK can't get SQLite table, because i truncated that at start. Logcat helped me understand what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to accept your answer after three days, it will help others who have similar issue.