# Xamarin.Forms apk file wont do anything, in live debugging it works perfectly

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Ive wanted to share my app to friends for testing-purposes. While everything worked fine while debugging, the app wont do anything once installed as pure apk. There are no error messages, the app just freezes before even the GUI appears.

What I've tried:
I built the  xamarin.forms project, archived the android project of it, clicked distribute -> Ad Hoc. Then I created a signature and copied the produced apk to my phone. 
I also enabled debugging in the release solution, expecting an error that only appears there, but this also wasn't the case.

How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Before you distribute your application, if you set the Linker Options? https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-linker/  If you set it, please set the value to `None`, re-distribute you application, if this issue is existed. Here is a similar thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630822/after-archiving-xamarin-forms-app-to-apk-it-does-not-work you can refer to it.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT it is not set.The problem still exists.

Comment: Please open your DDMS, then install this apk in your emulator, monitor the logcat, If you can got error message when you install the apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what helped, but I used the clean uninstall from adb, unclicked all permissions and I unchecked "Use Shared Runtime".

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please mark your answer after two days, it will help others who have similar issue.